# Python selenium click on button link

Tags: python, selenium

A quick question.  How do I click on the following button link using selenium in python?

```
<div class="load_more">
<a class="button button_grey" href="#">Load more</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use several approaches.  One I would suggest is by css selector:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.load_more>a").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

I also discovered that the following works:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Load more").click()
```